# SwiftUI List animation causes the app to show outdated results when the binding changes quickly

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to animate search changes in a list with SwiftUI 2 / Xcode 12, however the animation can't keep up when searching quickly. Originally this is within a project using a search bar through UIKit but I can reproduce this easily in SwiftUI alone:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var searchText = ""

    private var arrayToAnimate: [String] = ["aa", "aaa", "a", "fg", "fgh", "rd"]

    private func filtededListByValue(_ filterValue: String) -> [String] {
        return arrayToAnimate.filter { filterValue.isEmpty || $0.lowercased().contains(filterValue.lowercased()) }
    }

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Search text", text: $searchText) // $searchText.animation() has the same problem
        List {
            ForEach(filtededListByValue(searchText), id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
        }.animation(.easeIn) // When typing fast this causes the list to display incorrect data
    }

    /*
     // Using this instead has the exact same problem
     private var searchBinding: Binding<String> {
        Binding<String>(
            get: { return self.searchText },
            set: { newSearchText in
                withAnimation {
                    self.searchText = newSearchText
                }
            }
        )
    }*/
}
```

When slowly typing the results will be correct but if I for example type aaa and back to nothing fast then not all items will show even though there is no search text. If I use the get/set version of the binding instead it has the same problem. How do we handle this in SwiftUI? Is it a bug in SwiftUI? If I remove the animation it works.

Comment: Not reproducible for me with iOS 15 & Xcode 13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this since I can't reproduce this issue with SwiftUI 3. I assume it was a bug with SwiftUI 2.

Answer (score 0):

There really is no 'fix' for this. Your code is basically the most simplified example you can have for your goal. If you were making an api call it would be different. Try different animations, or using a completion handler for your filtering.